# I don't have the timings option in the node editor

Tags: node-editor, interface, shader-nodes, performance

Pretty much what I said in the title, even though I have blender 3.6.1, the timings option does not show up in the top right menu of the node editor (shading).

[image: An image of the node editor top right menu open, with the Wire Colors, Context Path and Annotations options visible]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timing option **exists only for the Geometry Nodes Editor** and not the Shader Editor.

Also the timings option doesn't even make sense while shading(except maybe a very few nodes) In the Geometry Nodes Editor however, it makes perfect sense to have it as you may need to keep things working in realtime for some reason. Or somtimes if the timings seem off you might have too much geometry or other problems before that node.

Comment: Oh my god, sorry, I'm so dumb. Thanks so much for the response, have a great day!!