How can I know shader statistics?
I want to understand, how much time my shader needs to calculate with each node details. Like texture sample node requires 0.13ms to calculate, invert color needs 0.01ms to calculate. Is there any addon for it or built-in solution?

See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298272/i-dont-have-the-timings-option-in-the-node-editor

@JohnEason well, I agree that purpose of timings of each nodes is questionable, but it will be helpful for people with weak pc, who wants to, at least, decrease the calculation timings.
